# MEVN app deployment to Heroku failed because of 'vue-cli-service' not found

Tags: vue.js, heroku, vue-cli

So, I tried to deploy my MEVN application to Heroku by following Traversy's tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71wSzpLyW9k). I followed all the steps that he outlined in the tutorial. His tutorial is for the MERN stack, but it's very similar apart from the front-end framework, so I figured it would work for my MEVN app too.

The main parts of the tutorial were adding this snippet to my app.js:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    //Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

and this script in package.json:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

The "heroku-postbuild" script ran when I did "git push heroku master", so it seemed like the deployment was going to work until it got to the point of trying to build the client side.

The details of the build log are below:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
   
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.2...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.5
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > puppeteer@3.0.1 install /tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/node_modules/puppeteer
       > node install.js
       
       
       
       > nodemailer@6.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/node_modules/nodemailer
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       === Nodemailer 6.4.6 ===
       
       Thank you for using Nodemailer for your email sending needs! While Nodemailer
       itself is mostly meant to be a SMTP client there are other related projects in
       the Nodemailer project as well.
       
       For example:
       > IMAP API (  https://imapapi.com  ) is a server application to easily access
       IMAP accounts via REST API
       > NodemailerApp (  https://nodemailer.com/app/  ) is a cross platform GUI app to
       debug emails
       
       
       > node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall /tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/node_modules/node-cron
       > opencollective-postinstall
       
       
       > bcrypt@4.0.1 install /tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/node_modules/bcrypt
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
         CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/src/nothing.o
         AR(target) Release/obj.target/../node-addon-api/src/nothing.a
         COPY Release/nothing.a
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
         COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
         COPY /tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node
         TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
       
       > nodemon@2.0.2 postinstall /tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       added 332 packages in 24.401s
       
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a
       > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
       
       
       > core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/client/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       added 15 packages from 14 contributors and audited 1360 packages in 9.661s
       
       2 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 261 low severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
       > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_44931d5da2ada9ea8e2cd227fa7e5a8a/client
       > vue-cli-service build
       
sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Bldog/_logs/2020-07-03T02_19_47_442Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Bldog/_logs/2020-07-03T02_19_47_458Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
Build finished
heroku.com
```

I couldn't find a solution for my particular situation that dealt with 'vue-cli-service' not found, so I'm asking here.

**EDIT:**

root folder package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "express-validator": "^6.4.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.10",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
```

client folder package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli": "^4.4.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.14",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3",
    "vuex-persist": "^2.2.0",
    "websocket-extensions": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  }
```

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#heroku

Comment: I have also encountered this problem, also after Traversy lesson. Ended up building frontend locally and uploading build folder to heroku

Comment: @DavidGo, so I guess you just ended up deploying two applications, front-end and back-end?

Comment: I deploy only back end part, and put builded frontend to it folder with this commsnd in Vue config  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),

Comment: btw, I remember that this video was helpful to me, maybe you should check it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PaUiPyBDJY&t=481s

Comment: @David Go, what does your "heroku-postbuild" script look like? Or did you remove that part?

Comment: I don't have one

Answer (score 0):

I assume that You have installed Heroku CLI, logged in and connected to Your github account.

If so this is how I've deployed my project.

...

I have created a new branch i.e. deployBranch

Then in the frontend folder I have run '***npm run build***'.

I have copied the '***dist***' folder to project folder.

In backend file (*server.js* or in your case *app.js*) I have added this code just after the routes:

```
const trajectory = path.resolve();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(trajectory, "/dist")));
    app.get("*", (req, res) =>
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(trajectory, "dist", "index.html"))
    );
}
```

(don't add ***heroku-postbuild*** script to package.json and delete */dist* from .gitignore file in master project folder if there is one)

After this I commited all the changes ***to a new branch***.

***git push --set-upstream origin deployBranch***

Then in heroku, i have created the new project.
In deploy section '**App connected to GitHub**' I have connected it to my project github repo.

I've changed the branch to deployBranch in '**Manual deploy**' and choose '**deploy branch**'

After that all that was left to do was to add **config vars** in the **settings** from ***.env***